# Change picture caption thru Graph Api C# Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to know if it's possible to change the caption of a picture uploaded in facebook.
I could upload without trouble, but now I want to change the caption using the facebook graph api. Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `name` field is what you want to POST to, in order to change the caption: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

However, they don't support writing to it. The things you can write are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing

It is possible to upload the photo with a new caption, but it looks as if the user has to approve the addition of a photo to his album, and I'm not sure that part is automatable.

Also, Facebook has blocked the ability to delete photos via the Graph API; so even with the approval barrier above you could not delete the photo with the old caption and upload it with a new caption, in order to effectively change the caption. The error message on sending the correct DELETE command is: `{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."}}`

So the short answer is "it is apparently not possible as of June 11 2011".

Comment: Still not possible to change caption of uploaded photo ?