# Facebook - Changing a photo caption via graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to change a caption of an image on Facebook in PHP via graph api? 
This is the way I used to upload it:

```
$facebook->api_client->photos_upload($file,$aid,'some caption',$uid);
```

Any hints?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685198/change-picture-caption-thru-graph-api-c-sharp-facebook You can find your anwser here.

Comment: Please answer the question yourself or ask @HenrikPeinar to do so :) thanks

Comment: It's not possible to change an image caption on Facebook using PHP at this time. More info here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685198/change-picture-caption-thru-graph-api-c-sharp-facebook

Comment: I had trouble changing the captions, added comment to another related question (stackoverflow.com/questions/8928656/) and lodged a bug with facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/201789646590720), if you too can repoduce the problem, then indicate that on the ticket, maybe it'll get more attention.

Comment: @SaharAtias Would it be okay to use an external tool ? Then i could deliver a sexy one liner

Answer (score 3):

NO, Its not possible to change caption of image using API.

Answer (score 1):

The Open Graph API does not allow such an option.

It is possible to upload the photo with a new caption, but it looks as if the user has to approve the addition of a photo to his album, and I'm not sure that part is automatable.

If you want further explination try reading [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685198/change-picture-caption-thru-graph-api-c-sharp-facebook) question.

I may be doing something wrong and should not answer as link to same question exists on the comments, but i just thought it's an answer and no one posted it.
If i shouldn't have done that, comment and i'll delete or author delete question.
Don't start voting me down =/

Answer (score 1):

You can't update captions on Facebook. They're quite rigid about that. You can upload a caption, but if it includes a link, it will be "red flagged" as spammy and your app might be taken down. The way they want you to do it is provide a text area for the user to fill out, and then upload that to Facebook. Essentially, have some user-moderated flow that allows someone to add or customize the caption input.

After it's uploaded, there's absolutely no way to change it.